# Getting TypeError: wsc.require is not a function for hyco-ws npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, node-modules, azure-hybrid-connections

I want to use this npm package in a service that currently works. When I run "npm run start", it fails and I get the error :

> TypeError: wsc.require is not a function
>       at Object../node_modules/hyco-ws/lib/HybridConnectionWebSocketServer.js
>   (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:80851:24)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:21:30)
>       at Object../node_modules/hyco-ws/index.js (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:80686:20)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:21:30)
>       at Object../source/backend/azure/EventGridClient.ts (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:235598:20)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:21:30)
>       at Object../source/backend/main.ts (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5\i******\lib\main.js:236679:27)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:21:30)
>       at Object.0 (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:238511:18)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\FreshClones\beconnect5******\lib\main.js:21:30) [web-serv]
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

*This is lines of code that are producing the error in the main.js file :*

```
var wsc = __webpack_require__.c[/*require.resolve*/(/*! ws */ "./node_modules/hyco-ws/node_modules/ws/index.js")]

const Extensions = wsc.require('./lib/Extensions');
```

**Note** "******" this refers to a foldername which I am hiding for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it myself, it was very simple.

We had a webpack.config.backend.js setup which was exporting modules into the lib folder's node modules after "npm run build". Just had to add my package in the module.exports.

```
    module.exports =  {
       externals:  ['utf-8-validate', 'bufferutil',{
          "hyco-ws": "hyco-ws",
           .................. ,
           .................. ,
           }]
     };
```